# Angular 2 / Rx object cast issue

Tags: angular, generics, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm using Angular 2.4.0 and Rx 5.0.0.

I'm using the following function in an injectable service to get data from a service:

```
public getStudy(id: number): Rx.Observable<Array<StudyViewModel>> {
   return this.http
      .get(this.seviceUrls.repositoryService + id)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((errors: any) => Rx.Observable.throw(errors.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

While this works, the object returned is of type "object". I was expecting to get an object of type "StudyViewModel". The properties are correct and the object does contain the expected data. But my "StudyViewModel" has decorators and those decorators are lost.

This is what the debugger says:

[image: Object returned in JavaScript]

When I explicitly create a new object of type "StudyViewModel" and return this, the expected type appears. I have actually this code to create sort of a shallow copy:

```
public getStudies(): Rx.Observable<Array<StudyViewModel>> {
  return this.http
    .get(this.seviceUrls.repositoryService)
    .map((res: Response) => {
      // force internal viewmodel type, required to access private decorators
      let model = <Array<StudyViewModel>>(res.json());
      let viewModel = new Array<StudyViewModel>();
      for (let i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
        viewModel.push(new StudyViewModel(model[i]));
      }
      return viewModel;
    })
    .catch((errors: any) => Rx.Observable.throw(errors.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

Now I get what I want, even in JavaScript in the debugger view:

[image]

You see some private properties I add using decorators. My viewmodel looks like this (just to complete the story):

```
export class StudyViewModel {

constructor(source?: {}) {
  const obj = {} as StudyViewModel;
   // source can be any json
   for (var p in source) {
     if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
       this[p] = source[p];
     }
  }
}

id: number;

@Display("Short Name", "This is the short name")
@Required()
@MaxLength(28)
shortName: string;
}
```

The decorators create hidden properties I use later to resolve the content. That's why I need "my" viewmodel, not the object actually sent from server.

**What am I missing? Why does an Observable foes not return the generic type?**

Thanks for any hints! Merry Christmas!

Comment: You're not missing anything, and you found the solution to your problem. How could the completely generic Response.json() method know about your class and create instances of it. It just uses JSON.parse() which returns basic JavaScript objects.

Comment: In addition, I assume a simple casting (`.map((res: Response) => <Array<StudyViewModel>> res.json()`) might be sufficient, since the initial approach tells me you don't need to create `new StudyViewModel`s to trigger the `constructor` at all. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: @naeramarth7 yes, you're wrong. "casting", as you call it, doesn't change the type of objects. And as clearly explained by the OP, the array he gets from .json() is not an Array<StudyViewModel>. "Casting" would only tell the typescript compiler: you can't know what the type is, because json() returns any, but trust me, I know it's an Array<StudyViewModel>. But it's not.